# Blog.stackexchange logo.png not displaying for multiple users

Tags: bug

I went to [blog.stackexchange](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) this morning and it would appear the logo link is bad:

[image]

I didn't know if this was the correct location for this so my apologies and if you need me to post it somewhere else I will be happy to do so.

Another user sees this:

[image]

The image url directs to a `not found` in chat.

Comment: Complete norepro

Comment: This may have been an error message cached by CloudFlare.  The cache has been cleared, can you reproduce the issue still?